# Everytime I add a goup Id in a groups array for a user and then log out, the authentication breaks and it keeps telling me invalid password

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, mongoose, jwt

I am making an application where I have users and groups. Users are able to make accounts and create a group. When a user creates a group, that group ID gets added to the groups array in the user schema. The problem I am facing is, when I create a group, add it to the user, and logout, when I try to log back in, it gives me the password invalid statement. I was wondering if anyone knows why?

My user Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Group = require('./group');
const {isEmail} = require('validator')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')

const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const userSchema = new Schema({
username:{
    type:String,
    required: [true, 'Please enter a username'], 
    unique: true
},
gmail:{ type: String,
    required:[true,'Please enter a gmail'],
    unique: true,
    lowercase: true,
    validate: [isEmail, 'Please enter a valid email']
},
password:{
    type: String, 
    required: [true, 'Please enter a password'],
    minlength: [6, 'Please enter a minimum of 6 characters']
},
groups:[{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'group'
}]
})

// execute a function BEFORE (pre) doc saved in db
userSchema.pre('save', async function(next){
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt()
    this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt)
    next()
    
})

// static method to login user
userSchema.statics.login = async function(gmail, password){
    // get user
    const user = await this.findOne({gmail})
    // check if user exists
    if(user){
        const auth = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
        if(auth){
            return user
        }
        throw Error('Incorrect Password')
    }
    throw Error('Incorrect Gmail')
}

const Users = mongoose.model('user',userSchema)

module.exports = Users;
```

My Group schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Users = require('./users');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const groupSchema = new Schema({
    _groupid:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    groupName:{type:String,require:[true, 'Please enter a Group Name']},

},{timestamps:true})

const Group = mongoose.model('group',groupSchema)

module.exports = Group;
```

My Login post function:

```
module.exports.login_post= async (req, res)=>{
    const {gmail, password} = req.body
    try{
        const user = await User.login(gmail, password)
        const token = createToken(user._id)
        res.cookie('jwt', token, {httpOnly: true, maxAge : maxAge})
        res.status(200).json({user: user._id})
        
    }
    catch(err){
        const errors = handleErrors(err)
        res.status(400).json({errors})
    }
}
```

My create group function:

```
app.post('/createGroup', requireAuth,async (req, res)=>{
    try{
        const {groupName} = req.body

        res.status(200).json({group: group._id})
        if(token){
            jwt.verify(token, JWT_SECRET,async (err, decodedToken)=>{
                if(err){
                    console.log(err.message);
                }else{

                    console.log("DecodedToken:" ,decodedToken);
                    const group = await Group.create({groupName})
                    let user = await User.findById(decodedToken.id)
                    user.groups.push(group)
                    user.save()
    

                    res.status(200).json({group: group._id})
            }
        })

    }

}
    catch(err){
        const errors = handleErrors(err)
        res.status(400).json({errors})

    }
})
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance

I tried to logging out with out creating groups and it works just fine. So I am assuming it has something to do with my JWT token verification.

Answer (score 0):

I think issue might be when you are trying to save the `user` after adding `group` to it.

Since `save` is async in nature, you should be awaiting for it.

In function `app.post('/createGroup')` you should do

`await user.save()`

If you don't `await` it won't save the updated user and might cause issue when you create JWT token

Comment: Hey, thank you for the suggestion, it makes sense. I added it but it did not work. I still get the same error.